# Как организовать поиск по адресам и по организациям одновременно?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Задача:

Имеется сервис вызова такси. На форме заказа есть инпут для ввода адреса. При вводе адреса пользователю должны показываться подходящие варианты адресов и организаций (торговые центры и прочее).

Проблема:

Есть геокодер в JS-API, который подходит для поиска адресов. Есть также сервис https-запросов для поиска по организациям. Но как их совместить?

В ответе на каждый из запросов приходят по несколько результатов из разных городов, при этом нестрогое сужение области поиска по координатам прямоугольника города  лишь сортирует результаты, оставляя нерелевантные (отдалённые) в списке.

Суть проблемы:

Находясь в городе N попробуем найти адреса и объекты по слову «Офицерская»

геокодер нам вернёт несколько улиц с таким названием, пару из города N, ещё сколько-то из соседних городов и ещё откуда-то.

поиск по организациям вернёт офецерскую столовую в городе N, офицерский рынок в соседнем городе и парк офицеров где нибудь в Магадане.

Такой список показывать пользователем нельзя, пользоваться им не возможно. Пользователь не понимает что первыми показываются организации, а там внизу где-то адреса или наоборот. Для него это выглядит как свалка нерелевантных результатов.

Что же делать? может есть иной инструмент?

Answer (score 1):

В JS API есть провайдер поиска `yandex#search`, который [позволяет](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo?from=SO) искать как топонимы (адреса), так и организации. При этом тип запроса может определяться автоматически: сервис анализирует запрос и предлагает либо данные по адресам, либо организации; или его можно задать самостоятельно. 
Влиять на ранжирование результатов нельзя.

Также есть возможность использовать и [Геокодер](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/?from=SO) и [Поиск по организациям (Геопоиск)](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geosearch/concepts/request-docpage/?from=SO) через HTTP-запросы.

Чтобы результаты поиска были правильными, стоит ограничивать область поиска. В JS API для этого есть параметр [`boundedBy`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#param-parameters.options.boundedBy?from=SO), а в HTTP API - `bbox`. Это позволит исключить результаты вне нужного города.

Для поисковых подсказок использовать Поиск и Геокодер не стоит, во-первых, они не предназначены для поиска по частичному вводу (могут быть очень странные результаты), во-вторых, подсказки будут генерировать очень много запросов, которые ограничены в бесплатной версии. 
Для поисковых подсказок нужно использовать [`SuggestView`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView-docpage/?from=SO). [Вот пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest?from=SO).

Comment: А можно ли как-то пользоваться провайдером yandex#search без использования контрола SearchControl?

У меня кастомный инпут вне карты, мне нужно получить результаты поиска, каким-то образом их обработать и вывести в кастомный список, назначить кастомные события на элементы этого списк и т.п.

Comment: Такую задачу стоит решать через HTTP API Поиска по организациям, в JS API условия использования бесплатной версии запрещают видоизменять результаты поиска, скрывать рекламу, отображать их вне карты и т.д.